# Postgres - Replace full String including occurances using regexp_replace

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, regexp-replace, postgres-14

I am using Postgres `regexp_replace` method to :

Replace `*.dataMain AS *__dataMain,` full Row as Empty,
where * can be any alias for ex. `m`, `n`, `m2`, `n1`, etc any alphanumeric.

I have below sample data :

```
n.dataPrev AS n__dataPrev,
n.dataMain AS n__dataMain,
m.dataPrev2 AS m__dataPrev,
m.dataMain AS m__dataMain,
m.dataNext2 AS m_dataNext2
```

Expected Output :

```
n.dataPrev AS n__dataPrev,
m.dataPrev2 AS m__dataPrev,
m.dataNext2 AS m_dataNext2
```

Below is my test `regexp_replace` method usage to try :

```
select regexp_replace(
'n.dataPrev AS n__dataPrev, n.dataMain AS n__dataMain, m.dataPrev2 AS m__dataPrev, m.dataMain AS m__dataMain, m.dataNext2 AS m_dataNext2',
'[^:\s]+dataMain(\S+)', '');
```

Getting below as output :

```
n.dataPrev AS n__dataPrev,
n.dataMain AS 
m.dataPrev2 AS m__dataPrev,
m.dataMain AS m__dataMain,
m.dataNext2 AS m_dataNext2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
select regexp_replace(
'n__dataPrev, n.dataMain AS n__dataMain, n.dataNext
 m__dataPrev2, m.dataMain AS m__dataMain, m.dataNext2',
', [^,]* AS [^,]*,', ',','g');
```

The regex I am using:

```
, [^,]* AS [^,]*,
```

It is searching for "AS" and matches everything between the 2 commas.
I changed the flag to 'g' as well which replaces all occurrences instead of only the first. Let me know if this works for you.

**Update**
If you only want to match dataMain try this Regex:

```
,[^,]*dataMain[^,]*,
```

Comment: Thanks for efforts, I updated the sample data, So the column is containing full sql inside, where I want to remove certain column definition itself in selection. Hence it will replace all the column definitions instead on the specific column, Can you update answer for single column ? for ex only for `dataMain` ?

Comment: @LuFFy added another regex. Does this one match your use case?